# CSS3 animate only on hover on and off

Tags: html, css

I have an animation of a box, where it's width increases on hover:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hbpncv34/

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;
}
div:hover {
    animation: change_width 0.7s forwards;
}
@keyframes change_width {
    from {
        width: 10vw;
    }
    to {
        width: 15vw;
    }
}
```

**Issue:**

I also want the box to smoothly move back when I hover off of it.

There are two ways I could do this:

#### Method 1:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hbpncv34/1/

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;
    
    animation: change_width_back 0.7s forwards;
}
div:hover {
    animation: change_width 0.7s forwards;
}
@keyframes change_width {
    from {
        width: 10vw;
    }
    to {
        width: 15vw;
    }
}
@keyframes change_width_back {
    from {
        width: 15vw;
    }
    to {
        width: 10vw:
    }
}
```

**Issue:**

The `change_width_back` animation also runs on page load.

Also, mousing on / off rapidly is not smooth like it is with `transition`, so:

#### Method 2:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hbpncv34/2/

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;
    transition: width 0.7s;
}
div:hover {
    width: 15vw;
}
```

**Issue:**

The animation also runs on zooming in and out.

I can fix this by using `px` or `%` instead of `vw` for my widths, but it's crucial in my actual issue that I keep it as viewport units.

So, is there any way to play an animation on hover on and off, and **only** hover on and off?

Since I don't know Javascript, please keep answers HTML / CSS only. If JS is *absolutely needed*, make it simple enough to just copy + paste with minimal editing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way, but with very little `js` combined to your `Method 1`, you can do this:

```
<div onmouseover="this.classList.add('animate')"></div>
```

And in your css:

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;

}
div.animate
 {
     animation: change_width_back 0.7s forwards;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vhyfewnt/

EDIT

First solution is meant to work with animate, not with transition. There's a way to make transition work, but it needs a little more javascript.

```
<body onresize="document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].classList.add('zoom'); setTimeout(function(e){document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].classList.remove('zoom')}, 100)">
<div></div>
</body>

div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;

}
div:not(.zoom)
{
    transition: width 0.7s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 15vw;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cdj7L5r3/

2nd EDIT:

To apply to more elements, you can add the class to body (or any ancestor) and change the rule. Like this:

```
<body onresize="document.body.classList.add('zoom'); setTimeout(function(e){document.body.classList.remove('zoom')}, 100)">
<div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <section></section>
</body>

div, section{
    background-color: red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;

}
body:not(.zoom) div, body:not(.zoom) section
{
    transition: width 0.7s;
}

div:hover, section:hover {
    width: 15vw;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cdj7L5r3/1/

Comment: The class doesn't seem to go away when the mouse moves away: https://jsfiddle.net/vhyfewnt/1/ . I was trying it with transition because that's smoother.

Comment: see edit, no the class stays. 'Animate' is the wrong name, it should be "activated" or something like that. It's only to prevent the animation on load, afterwards, it just stays there.

Comment: When using `transition`, there is no need to have the on-load prevention. The only issue is zooming. I see you have fixed both in the new JSFiddle; can you remove the on-load prevention? Then your answer will be, like, perfect. :]

Comment: Ah, never mind --  I think I'm mistaken. Then, this answer is great! Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with everything, not just `div`s? I tried `document.getElementsByTagName('*')`; it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You need "ready" state flag in order to accomplish this:

```js
$(function(){

 $("div").attr("ready",true);

});
```

```css
div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;
    
}

div[ready] {
  transition: width 0.7s;
}

div[ready]:hover {
    width: 15vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>.</div>
```

Comment: Good solution. The OP really has strange requirements. Who cares what a page does *while* it is being zoomed??

Comment: @conexo I tend to try to make things perfect :/

Comment: Great solution but why doesn't work when the snippet is in Full page, I'm using chrome Version 34.0.1807.0

Comment: Great solution! I'll try it ASAP. To do this for all elements, can I just replace `("div")` with `("*")`?

Comment: @YandYViera Works for me full page. What browser are you on?

Comment: I'm using chrome Version 34.0.1807.0 and FF version 38.0.5

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/kxwcjv09/, if I zoom the page the animation also runs on zooming in and out. I copy paste the snippet in the jsfiddle. What I'm doing wrong, it is for my browsers ?

Comment: @c-smile Actually, this doesn't seem to work -- the bar still moves upon zoom.

Comment: @Quelklef what does "zoom" mean in this case?

Comment: `Ctrl`+`+`, `Ctrl`+`-`, `Ctrl`+`Scroll wheel`, etc. (keyboard markup isn't working for me)

Comment: @Quelklef then it means that computed values of `height: 10vh;  width: 10vw;` properties will change and so they will be animated. I don't think that using computed values instead of declared value is a good behavior but that's how they implement it. Could be a bug in specification/implementation in browser code.

Answer (score 1):

**RE: animate on zoom in/out**, I don't think you're going to find a way around the animation issue with the CSS transition solution, because zooming changes the viewport size, and your units are in terms of the viewport.  So when the viewport changes, those units have to be recalculated/repainted and that change is animated, as specified in the `transition` property.

If you could provide some background on the use case for this effect, we might be able to help think of another way to solve this problem.

Comment: This is why I included the answer without `transition`, instead using `animation`. So, by fixing the one issue with that, it could work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to add a litter js code maybe this help you, the key is that classes have the animation behavior, when the animation ends you remove the classes, so there is no transition when the page is zoom or loaded

```js
var element = $("div");

element.bind("mouseover", function(){
        $(this).removeClass('sh');
        $(this).addClass('lg');
    });

element.bind("mouseout", function(){
  $(this).addClass('sh');
  $(this).removeClass('lg');
});


/*this is for remove the class when animation ends*/
element.bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
  $(this).removeClass('sh');
});
```

```css
div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 10vw;
}

.lg{
    width: 15vw;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
}

.sh{
    width: 10vw;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

[**Here a jsfiddle example to play with**](https://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/mdjv5gy7/)